# When I get 'services has reached steady state', in Amazon ECS does it means some tasks had stopped?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

[image: ECS Service Events]

Does this means that my service tasks are stopping or it's ok to get these log messages?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

actually opposite this. The service scheduler reports status periodically. A normal state indicates that there is nothing for it to do -- all tasks are healthy, there are no scaling requests or deployments.

Answer (score 15):

No it doesn't mean that any of your tasks had stopped. If a task stops you will see an event that clearly states so and will include a link to the specific task that was stopped. For example you will get something like this "service xxx has stopped 1 running tasks: task xxx."

If no tasks have been created or stopped in the last six hours the ECS console will duplicate the last event message to let you know that everything works as expected.

From the ECS docs:

"To ensure that this event view is helpful, we only show the 100 most recent events and duplicate event messages are omitted until either the cause is resolved or six hours passes. If the cause is not resolved within six hours, you will receive another service event message for that cause."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-event-messages.html

Answer (score 2):

Check this thread here on the aws forums. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=182793

> This sounds like normal behavior. The service scheduler reports status periodically. A normal state indicates that there is nothing for it to do -- all tasks are healthy, there are no scaling requests or deployments. Are you seeing  any issues?

Comment: That link is dead now, but I found this one.  Thanks to Tom for sharing the original.  https://repost.aws/questions/QUsf9TOLy_QQGrYmMv9hBxUA/fargate-service-reboots-every-six-hours